# Странное поведение оператора "-d" в Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl

Доброго времени суток! Хочу скриптом вывести каталоги из заданной директории, но скрипт выводит только каталог с именем "temp" и больше ничего!

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

dir('C:\\');

sub dir {  
  # read directory
  opendir my $DIR, shift;
  my @dir = readdir $DIR;
  closedir $DIR;

  foreach my $f (@dir) {
    if (-d $f) { print $f, "\n" } # если убрать -d, то выводит всё содержимое каталога
  }
  return 0;
}
```

запуск:

```
C:\>perl script.pl
```

вывод:

```
temp
```

Что за странности?!))

ОС: Windows XP i386

Perl: Strawberry Perl 5.14.2

Всё что лежит в корне диска C:\

> `boot.ini
> Bootfont.bin
> bp7
> Config.Msi
> dev
> Documents and Settings
> Downloads
> IO.SYS
> MSDOS.SYS
> MSOCache
> NTDETECT.COM
> ntldr
> oracle
> pagefile.sys
> Program Files
> Quarantine
> SoftUpdateLog.txt
> strawberry
> SWSetup
> System Volume Information
> system.sav
> temp
> tmp
> ttn
> TTN_RW
> UniScan
> WINDOWS
> WinNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему у Вас каталог temp кроме корня присутствует еще и в текущей папке.

Весь фокус в том, что readdir возвращает только имя файла, без пути, соответственно -d у Вас проверяет наличие каталога не в корне, а в текущей папке.

Вам следует все таки записать в переменную переданный параметр (например в $dn) и при вызове -d передавать ей "$dn/$f" (ну или "$dn\\$f").

Comment: Так оно и есть. Я считывал каталоги в корне, а проверял в текущем)) Спасибо!